# Custom Binding vs standard Binding in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am adding Circles or editing the location of Circles in my project, as I add a new Circle to my array if I use **approach 1** it make the unneeded renders happen, in the oder hand using the **approach 2** does solve all issue with extra renders!

Frankly for me both approach are the same but why make so big difference for SwiftUI?

**Why a custom Binding can solve the issue while standard Binding fails?**

Looking for a good and simple explain to understand what happens here.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var shapeArray: [ShapeTypeItem] = [ShapeTypeItem(id: 0, offset: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0), color: .red),
                                                      ShapeTypeItem(id: 1, offset: CGSize(width: 250.0, height: 50.0), color: .green)]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { _ in
            
            ForEach(shapeArray, id:\.id) { item in
                
                // approach 1:
                //ShapeTypeView(shapeTypeItem: $shapeArray[item.id])

                // approach 2:
                ShapeTypeView(shapeTypeItem: Binding.init(get: { () -> ShapeTypeItem in return shapeArray[item.id] },
                                             set: { (newValue) in shapeArray[item.id] = newValue }))
                
            }
  
        }
        .overlay(Button(action: {
            
            let random1 = CGFloat.random(in: 50...250)
            let random2 = CGFloat.random(in: 50...250)
            
            shapeArray.append(ShapeTypeItem(id: shapeArray.count, offset: CGSize(width: random1, height: random2), color: .blue))
            
        }, label: { Image(systemName: "plus.circle").font(Font.largeTitle.bold()).padding() }), alignment: .bottom)
        
        
    }
    
}


struct ShapeTypeItem: Identifiable {
    
    let id: Int
    var offset: CGSize
    var color: Color
    
}


struct ShapeTypeView: View {
    
    @Binding var shapeTypeItem: ShapeTypeItem
    
    var body: some View {
        
        print("rendering for id:", shapeTypeItem.id)
        
        return Circle().fill(shapeTypeItem.color)
            .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0, alignment: .center)
            .offset(shapeTypeItem.offset)
            .onTapGesture { shapeTypeItem.offset.height += 10.0 }
    }
    
}


extension ShapeTypeView: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ShapeTypeView, rhs: ShapeTypeView) -> Bool {
        (lhs.shapeTypeItem.id == rhs.shapeTypeItem.id) && (lhs.shapeTypeItem.offset == rhs.shapeTypeItem.offset)
    }
}
```

Comment: not clear what issue you are trying to "solve" here. Can you explain a bit more. As far as I can tell both approaches work for me.

Comment: @workingdog: I never said they do not working! what was deference of both approaches for you?

Comment: ha I see, so when you have your question "Why a custom Binding can solve the issue while standard Binding fails?", you don't actually have an issue that you are trying to solve, do you. And "... standard Binding fails", is not failing is it.  Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using item.id as index into shapeArray. It will behave oddly when you reorder the items in your array and it's [discouraged by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021-10018/?time=455). Instead, they proposed [the following solution](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021-10018/?time=488) during WWDC 2021:

> Simply pass a binding to your collection into the list, using the
> normal dollar sign operator, and SwiftUI will pass back a binding to
> each individual element within the closure.

So you should consider this third option:

```
// inside geometry reader in ContentView:
ForEach($shapeArray, id:\.id) { $item in
    ShapeTypeView(shapeTypeItem: $item)
}
```

Comment: I tried your given code, error: `Cannot declare entity named '$item'; the '$' prefix is reserved for implicitly-synthesized declarations` Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)

Comment: This will only work in Xcode 13 and onwards